# how to calculate required memory for a signal or structure in C

Tags: c

I have recently started to work in C. I was going through some code exercises to get some knowledge about signals. I know that `alloc()` is used to allocate memory for signals. in the following code `len` is my `data_len` which is defined in the structure. Have a look to the following scenario.

```
#define DATA_SEND   (SIGBASE + 1)
struct data_send
{
  uint32_t       sig_no  ;
  uint32_t       seq_no  ;
  uint32_t       data_len;
  uint32_t       type    ;   
  char           data[1] ;    
};

signal = (struct data_send *) alloc(sizeof(struct data_send) + len - 1,
           DATA_SEND);
```

My question is why do we do `+len and -1` while allocating memory for this signal. When we do `sizeof(struct data_send)` we are allocating memory for all the variables in the structure. Does this `-1` has to do anything with `data[1]` ? could someone explain to me the reason to have `+len and -1`.

Comment: Which alloc is this? malloc or calloc?

Comment: keep in mind that not all (and the most of) objects/structs in C do not need dynamic allocation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, data[1] is already 1 char long, so this is included in `sizeof(struct data_send)`.  So, `sizeof(struct data_send) + len` would yield a block which is slightly longer than necessary.

Comment: This technique is referred to as "the struct hack".

Comment: a very nice explanation.  Appreciated :)

Comment: I edited the question to remove my suggestion that you should not rely on the fact that char will always be 1 byte long.  I did it because another user said that `char` will always be 1 byte long, by definition.  This is not an absolute truth, but I would not be willing to argue against it, so, I removed the suggestion.